# Data Pass to another page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a html form to select a report type, 
when i select a report and press submit button, 
I can catch that passing value and 
I filter data from database, 
then I have to pass that filtered data to another page to print that report,

so how can i pass data to another page automatically. (page should option in  _blank)

Comment: if small amount of data then use $_SESSION for storage for next usage
http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php
 or else send the data in url encoded/ json format with pageurl

Comment: Either add it to a session or store the value(s) in a hidden form field.

Comment: On the php side, you can use a database, sessions, cookies or a file. On the javascript side, you can use localStorage, sessionStorage and cookies. Although, I would highly recommend not using cookies.

Comment: u can use request object to catch the named parameters in the next page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the hidden fields to store the data.
And submit the form explicitly to another page using :

```
 $('form#FormID').submit();
```

This will help you get the data on the next page.
You can also use $_SESSION .

Answer (score 1):

in your .php page

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="other.php" method="post">
   Name: <input type="text" name="name">
   Email: <input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

other.php

```
<html>
<body>

  Hi <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>!<br>
  Your mail is <?php echo $_POST["mail"]; ?>.

</body>
</html>
```